# xmppframework (iOS) receives didNotAuthenticate even the username and password are provided and correct

Tags: ios, authentication, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm now working on a strange issue regarding XMPP authentication.

The problem I face is that, the `didNotAuthenticate` is called even though the username and password provided is correct.

As per enterprise requirement, the user name and password are stored locally in the iOS app. Thus, it is confirmed that they are not entered incorrectly, and we have no change on server side.

While the iOS app is running as usual, it sometimes will get the method `(xmppStream:didNotAuthenticate:)` called.

My guess is while the app is running on 3G network, the connection is lossy, and the app will be reconnected. It seems like the case has a higher chance if the connection is really bad.

I'm not able to always reproduce the error. Has anyone faces a similar case before or can provide me some guidance on debugging?

Environment:

- OpenFire Server 3.7.1
- XMPPFramework for iOS (3rd version)
- iPhone 4S (iOS 6.0.1)

Comment: Are you saying it sometimes authenticates successfully and sometimes doesn't? Would you post your code?

Comment: I'm not sure which segments of the code is needed. However, my current findings are, after `authenticateWithPassword:error:` is called, the first response of handsake comes with 401 error code

Comment: Sounds like the username or password is wrong.

Comment: I have logged down the username and password, they are correct before passing to XMPP, encrypted using Digest-MD5

Comment: I think you'll need to post the parts of your code related to connecting and authenticating.